# SSRS URL Parameter Value does not match with report parameter Values

Tags: parameters, reporting-services

We have rdl report and passing a multiple paramter values through URL. When the passed values exists in report parameter values then report displayes properly.

But when we pass the values through URL which doesn't exists in report parameter value then it throws an error saying parameter value is missing.

The reports db and the application db through which we display the reports are different. how do we address this issue.

pls help.

regards,
hari.

Comment: Why are the available values on the deployed reports derived from the reports db instead of the application db?

Answer (score 0):

I would try adding default values to your parameters, or allow nulls for your parameters.  This way the report will not complain when no value is passed for a specific parameter.